# Retrieving connection status

Tags: mysql

Is there a way the `status` command be called on another connection. Something like:

```
status 231073
```

where the number is the ID from SHOW PROCESSLIST. In particular I'm interested in connection/client character sets.

EDIT:
By `status` I mean the command you call from the MySQL shell (not `show status`)

Comment: I believe you would need to trick er program it so that each client connection runs `show status`, you capture the resultset, and publish it to a client session worktable. Shouldn't be too hard in any language.

Comment: @Drew `show status` doesn't show character encodings

Comment: which status are you referring to. Improve the question

Comment: ok, same difference, `show session variables like '%character_set%'` coupled with `select connection_id();` ... jam that info with a datetime into a worktable

Comment: `SHOW SESSION...` applies to _your_ connection, not anyone else's.

Comment: Unlike its name, `SHOW ... VARIABLES` contains the settings.  As Drew's answer points out _some_ of them can be changed during the connection.  I don't think there is any way to see the changed value from an I_S table or otherwise from outside the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to capture info of your connections, say, at the start of your app or at anytime. For instance `max_allowed_packet` could change during the client run lifecycle. So, in short, have in as part of your app startup.

Then you have collected info on your client connections, such as character set settings.

Schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS connectionSnapshot;
CREATE TABLE connectionSnapshot
(   -- based off of (more or less) mysql 5.6 show create table information_schema.PROCESSLIST;
    -- 3 columns at least
    -- TODO: compare to same structure on mysql 5.7
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    connId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    user VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    host VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    login VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    -- the followed just dreamt up:
    character_set_client VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    character_set_connection VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    character_set_results VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    collation_connection VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    lc_time_names VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    max_allowed_packet BIGINT NOT NULL,
    time_zone VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    theWhen DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspConnectionSnapshotMe;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE uspConnectionSnapshotMe()
BEGIN
    DECLARE lconnId INT;
    DECLARE luser VARCHAR(16);
    DECLARE lhost VARCHAR(64);
    SELECT connection_id() INTO lconnID;
    SELECT USER,HOST into luser,lhost FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID=lconnId;

    INSERT connectionSnapshot (connId,user,host,login,character_set_client,character_set_connection,character_set_results,
    collation_connection,lc_time_names,max_allowed_packet,time_zone,theWhen) VALUES 
    (lconnId,luser,lhost,current_user(),@@session.character_set_client,@@session.character_set_connection,
    @@session.character_set_results,@@session.collation_connection,
    @@session.lc_time_names,@@session.max_allowed_packet,@@session.time_zone,now());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
-- ****************************************************************************************
```

Test:

```
call uspConnectionSnapshotMe();
```

Results:

```
select * from connectionSnapshot;
+----+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | connId | user | host            | login          | character_set_client | character_set_connection | character_set_results | collation_connection | lc_time_names | max_allowed_packet | time_zone | theWhen             |
+----+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |   3825 | root | localhost:4660  | root@localhost | utf8                 | utf8                     | utf8                  | utf8_general_ci      | en_US         |            4194304 | SYSTEM    | 2016-09-08 02:40:18 |
|  2 |  37007 | root | localhost:52071 | root@localhost | utf8                 | utf8                     | cp850                 | utf8_general_ci      | en_US         |            4194304 | SYSTEM    | 2016-09-08 02:44:17 |
+----+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```