# MariaDB will not change the collation for a database

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, heidisql

I have been researching this problem on StackOverflow for more than 24 hours and decided that this isn't already covered elsewhere even though there are many Q&A about the same topic.

I am using HeidiSQL 9.3 against MariaDB 10.1 and have a strange problem as follows: I originally accepted the default collation when I created my database then realized that this wasn't what I wanted and tried to change it with

`ALTER DATABASE InternalFulfillment CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

This has no effect, and the database is still reported as `ucs2_bin` and all of the procedures and functions are `ucs2_bin` as well. I tried all of the advice from every Q&A I could find on StackOverflow including these statements:

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';
```

When I drop and recreate the procedures they still come back as `ucs2_bin`.

The strangest thing of all is that if I drop and recreate the database with the name 'InternalFulfilment' the collation is wrong, but if I create a database with a different name then I get the collation I want, and running the script that creates the stored procedures creates procedures with the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

It seems like MariaDB and/or HeidiSQL is remembering the original collation that I used when I first created the 'InternalFulfillment' database, and always uses `ucs2_bin` collation whenever I create a database with this name.

Does anyone have any idea where this might be stored so I can clear it. Thanks.

**Additional comments after reading answers below**

After leaving this overnight, the next morning I was able to drop and recreate the database with a different collation, but now it is stuck on the new collation.

Following on from the answer from @Anse:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `InternalFulfillment`;

CREATE DATABASE `InternalFulfillment` /*!40100 COLLATE 'ucs2_bin' */;

USE `InternalFulfillment`;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `column1` VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
COLLATE='ucs2_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `proc1`(IN `param1` VARCHAR(50))
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SELECT
        column1
    FROM
        table1 t
    WHERE
        t.column1 = param1;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL proc1('test');
```

Produces: `/* SQL Error (1267): Illegal mix of collations (ucs2_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' */`. If I re-run this script with `utf8mb4_general_ci` then it completes without error.

Yesterday my database was stuck in `ucs2_bin` and today it is stuck in `utf8mb4_general_ci` so there is something that is cached with a fairly long expiry time.

Comment: interesting trivia question. Note there are server global level and session level vars. Also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html

Comment: I wrote this up [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39384425) for snapshotting client-side and session vars as a stub. Also chatted with Rick about it [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32740569#32740569) ... messed around with it for a while and took it a little further on my own. I will ping Rick to take a look.

Comment: Would be good to know which MariaDB do you use? What does select * from information_schema.schemata where schema='InternalFulfillment'  return? Did you also try with command line client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is some collation cache in MariaDB. I'm the author of HeidiSQL, and I'm pretty sure there is no such collation cache thing in HeidiSQL itself, so it must be a MySQL and/or MariaDB issue.

However, I just tried to reproduce the issue on a MySQL v5.7.9 server on my local Windows, without luck:

```
CREATE DATABASE `InternalFulfillment` /*!40100 COLLATE 'ucs2_bin' */;
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `Column 1` VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
COLLATE='ucs2_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Both the database and table1 have `ucs2_bin` collation, as expected.

```
ALTER DATABASE `internalfulfillment` COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `Column 1` VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now, the database and the newly created table2 report the changed collation, as expected:

```
SELECT `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`
  WHERE `SCHEMA_NAME`='internalfulfillment';
>> utf8mb4_general_ci

SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='internalfulfillment';

TABLE_NAME | TABLE_COLLATION 
table1 | ucs2_bin 
table2 | utf8mb4_general_ci
```

So, my guess is that you have hit a bug in MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on HeidiSQL. See my additional comments in the question above. I think you are right, this must be a bug in MariaDB 10.1. I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @bikeman868 Has this bug been filed? It still seem to exist in MariaDB 10.5.5.

Comment: I got my MariaDB instance back into a state, where it will now immediately apply the `alter database` statement (and update its internal state), by executing a couple of `FLUSH QUERY CACHE; FLUSH TABLES; USE SomeDatabase;` statements. It did not dig deeper into why it works, but it did. Afterwards, creating and altering databases just works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Check these:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'; -- If anything say 'ucs2...', you should change it
SHOW CREATE DATABASE ...; -- The /*!40100 */ 'comment' is for hiding the clause for old versions.
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE ...\G
```

Some basics (which you seem to already understand):

The `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` on a database are only *defaults* for when you do `CREATE TABLE` without specifying them.

Similarly, the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` specified for a table are only *defaults* for for the columns.

To change the `COLLATION` for a given column(s), you need to use `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...`.

To change the *defaults*, `ALTER` can be used on the database or table; but that only affects *future* tables or columns.

Another issue...  The `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for any stored routine is defined when the routine is declared.  To change either or both of those, you must `DROP` and `reCREATE` the routine.

Going forward, `utf8mb4` is the main `CHARACTER SET` to use.  `ucs2` (and most of the other charsets) should almost never be used.  If you can discover where "ucs2" originated, root it out.